# DataGrid column header isn't filled with color properly (DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want my datagrid columns have one style and be filled with one colour. I wrote and applied the style I want and everything works fine except color of columns. I don't know why but columns are filled only were text exsit. As we can see borders are drawn properly but half of the column isn't:

[image]

```
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFF5FD"/>--> comment
                        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="10" Text="{Binding}" Padding="4"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

If I uncomment line and `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFF5FD"/>` is available I will have 1 solid colored column without any borders what I don't want:
[image]

My question is: how can I apply one style to all datagrid column headers to fill them with color and have borders between them?

Comment: Try <Setter Property="Background" Value="#EFF5FD" BorderThickness=1 BorderBrush="Black"/>

Comment: @NawedNabiZada, Thanks! So simple but works perfectly for me